# Polymorphic Array class Rules (Supermarket program)

Tags: java, polymorphism, uml, factory, class-diagram

So I have a class called `UserList` which contains an attribute called `Users` which is an `ArrayList` of my abstract class `User`.

[image]

My `User` Class has subclasses `Customer` and `Owner`.

[image]

[image]

Within the `UserList` I create new types of user based on my file which I load inside the `UserList` class.

[image]

When the File loads in I have method inside `UserList` that creates an `Owner`. It checks if there is 1 owner inside the file. If there is no `Owner` or more than one owner it throws an error.

Does it make sense to have a `UserList` class or rather a `CustomerList` class and an `Owner` class (given that my `UserList` class would connect my supermarket program)?

If these rules apply can I have methods in my `UserList` class that verifies the type of user (`Customer`,`Owner`) like `boolean IsOwner(User CurrentUser)` and `boolean IsCustomer(User CurrentUser)`?

Also considering that my program will be able to implement Employees in the future I feel like the `UserList` class makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, it's a lot easier to show your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Proper form on this site would be to upvote and accept answers to previous questions before asking more.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I cannot upvote your last comment. My reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: If you model individual roles, as I recommended in your last question, you would only need to count how many account instances are linked to the owner role instance.

Comment: Extending `User` makes it difficult for an owner to shop at his own store. People gain and lose roles all the time, so representing roles rigidly will often cause problems.

Comment: Yeah that's a good way of thinking about it thank you.

Comment: Just for the future (if you're asking code specific things): post the code, not a picture of it. (I think in this case it was ok with the picture, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserList`, `CustomerList`, `SoleOwnerList`, `EmployeeList` all make sense depending on your intent.

If your intent is to manage a list of users, just go for the `UserList` !   Generalization is meant to be able to cope with such case were users are something more general to mean different categories of users.

But I tell you something that you already know:

> Also considering that my program will be able to implement Employees
>   in the future I feel like the UserList class makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Yeah, it's the first iteration of the code to the bespoke user so i think it may be best to keep it generic and flexible.